# PixelSearch only in middle area?

Tags: autohotkey

so im playing Ragna and i want to afk some time while leveling my char. my script is doing good, but how can i pixelsearch/attack only the middle area?

heres the picture
[image: http://i60.tinypic.com/t681md.png]

```
loop {
    ; this is the color of green boxed monsters to attack
    PixelSearch, X, Y, 0, 0, %A_ScreenWidth%, %A_ScreenHeight%, 0x00FF00, 0, fast

    if (ErrorLevel = 0) {
        MouseClick, left, %X%, %Y%
    }
    else {
        ; if no monster present in screen, press teleport to search monsters
        Send {F1}
    }
}
return
```

Comment: measure the coordinates with WindowSpy. Open WindowSpy by right-clicking on any AHK script in the taskbar and selecting it. // I suggest you then also take a look at [coordmode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/CoordMode.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at what the parameters for `PixelSearch` means:

```
PixelSearch, OutputVarX, OutputVarY, X1, Y1, X2, Y2, ColorID [, Variation, Fast|RGB]
```

Source: [ahkscript.org docs](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/PixelSearch.htm)

So what you are currently doing is creating a box from `(0, 0)` to `(screenWidth, screenHeight)`. You could of course change it to hardcoded values or do some math based on the resolution, for example selecting a `200x200px` box in the middle:

```
leftBound   := A_ScreenWidth  / 2 - 100
rightBound  := A_ScreenWidth  / 2 + 100
topBound    := A_ScreenHeight / 2 - 100
bottomBound := A_ScreenHeight / 2 + 100

PixelSearch, X, Y, leftBound, topBound, rightBound, bottomBound, 0x00FF00, 0, fast
```

Comment: i dont know exactly what coordinates in middle. how can i know the exact middle coords?

Comment: Well, assuming you want to select a 200x200px rectangle around the middle of the monitor, this example would work. `A_ScreenWidth  / 2 ` of course is the middle of the monitor.

Comment: is this right? PixelSearch, X, Y, 0, 0, %A_ScreenWidth / 2%, %A_ScreenHeight / 2%, 0x00FF00, 0, fast

Comment: im not really full screen ..how about in 1024 x 768 in game window mode 
using the CoordMode, Pixel, Relative?

Comment: I'm not sure, try it out. I guess it should work pretty much they way you would expect it to work